# ORA-04098: trigger is invalid and failed re-validation

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I'm having trouble with a trigger I try to insert some data at the db

Here is the data I'm trying to insert

```
INSERT INTO login (login, senha) VALUES ('admin', 'admin')
```

The error

```
ORA-04098: trigger 'HOTEL.bi_login' is invalid and failed re-validation
```

The table and sequence

```
CREATE TABLE login(idLogin NUMBER(5), login VARCHAR2(50) UNIQUE, SENHA VARCHAR2(50), CONSTRAINT idLogin_pk PRIMARY KEY (idLogin));
CREATE sequence "login_seq";
```

And the Triger

```
  CREATE trigger "bi_login"
  before insert on login
  for each row
  DECLARE 
  qntdRows DATATYPE 
BEGIN 
  select "login_seq".nextval
  INTO qntdRows 
  FROM dual;
  :NEW.idLogin = qntdRows
END;
```

Comment: Missing semicolon after `:NEW.idLogin = qntdRows`. Just after running create trigger statement, just run `show errors` to check whether the trigger compiled fine or not. TIP: use `CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ...` command instead of `CREATE TRIGGER ...`. Another one: missing semicolon after `qntdRows DATATYPE`.

Comment: besides all, to use this better `qntdRows := login_seq.nextval;` instead to use with a "dual"

Comment: Also, what datatype is `DATATYPE` anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a couple of semicolons and the declaration of you variable should be NUMBER.

Please see below correct code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE trigger "bi_login"
  before insert on login
  for each row
DECLARE 
  qntdRows number;
BEGIN 
  select "login_seq".nextval
  INTO qntdRows 
  FROM dual;
  :NEW.idLogin := qntdRows;
END;
```

The above will replace your invalid trigger and will compile without any errors!

Furthermore, you can achieve the same with the below alternate code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE trigger "bi_login"
  before insert on login
  for each row
BEGIN 
  :NEW.idLogin := "login_seq".nextval;
END;
```

[Successful Compilation Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ac1UC.jpg)

I find it simpler and more elegant :)

Ted.

Comment: I've tried to use this two triggers you sent, but I'm still having the error when I try to insert into the table.

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting ORA-00001: unique constraint violated ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested ExDev second solution and its works well.

It probably did not work for you because you created other triggers in error state that are triggered at the same time. So, when you try to insert they are executed and you get the error because of them.

Solution: Check if you have others triggers created in past tries in error state and drop them. After that try the solution suggested by ExDev.